# ShareKit won't display all my Sharers

Tags: cordova, sharekit, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a PhoneGap (aka Cordova) project which makes use of [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). As instructed by the documentation [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/FAQ), I removed several of the unneeded "Sharers" and disabled the "more" button. When I build the project, instead of revealing the remaining sharers, it just removed the ones I deleted showing a shorter version of the original list.

How can I tell it to show the Sharers I want??

Right now I see:

- Email
- Twitter

That's it! How can I get this:

- Text message
- Twitter
- Facebook

The respective folders for these services were left in place, and their entries are in the correct order in the SHKSharers.plist (with actions on top and services below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is section Favorite sharers in ShareKit configurator. Fill in your desired sharers for each share type. Example:

```
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteURLSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKTwitter", @"SHKFacebook", @"SHKTextMessage", nil];
}
```

edit: Good question, thanks. I have improved ShareKit's FAQ to make it clear.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your assistance! Follow-up question: If I'm not using the Favorite sharers feature, will this still work for me? I had disabled it in the hopes of gaining more control over the list.

Comment: Can you explain how did you disable it?

Comment: One more - if you disabled Favourites feature, how do you get populated SHKActionSheet?

Comment: I changed `- (NSNumber*)autoOrderFavoriteSharers` to false. I found the instructions from second question here: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/FAQ

I'm not entirely clear how the action sheet gets populated. I was hoping it would simply show all the items on my preferences list, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Action sheet is populated by sharers specified in method(s) from my response. You should override it in your configurator subclass and put there sharers you desire. Normally last used sharer is on the top of the action sheet - "auto order". You disabled this, so you always see sharers specified in -(NSArray*)defaultFavorite...Sharers methods. And always in the same order returned from the functions.